# JGraphx pause execution. show point by point

Tags: jgraphx, jgraph

I have to show a graph with some points, i want that the points appear when it was generated, not all at end. I want to show the result point by point. I was looking for but i didnt find anything. is it possible?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you have made some attempt, please share that and someone is more likely to help you.

Comment: Did you have a look at `mxMorphing` ?